# Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.project.facet.WebProjectWizard"

Tags: eclipse

I am not able to create dynamic web project and getting this error
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui" was unable to instantiate class
"org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.project.facet.WebProjectWizard".

Also i have changed my workspace but getting the same error
Any help will appreciated

Comment: What version of Eclipse? On what version of Java? With what version of the org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui plug-in?

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: Eclipse version is : 2020-06(4.16.0) and java version is :"18.0.1.1" and Tomcat 9.0 i am using

Comment: Have you tried a version of Eclipse that came out after that version of the Java? They sometimes break things in the Java runtime.

Comment: No actually i have created my project 4 months back and at that time it was working for me and after that i have installed some sts  for spring so one of my batchmates told me to remove that plugins but after removing those plugins also i am getting the same error. So i am not able to run my project and also i am not able to create new dynamic web project.

Comment: Eclipse 2020-06 is almost three years and 11 releases behind. Please do not waste any more time and upgrade now!

Comment: Okay will upgrade thanks a ton

Comment: Trying to update but i don't know why it is not updating so i have reinstalled eclipse with latest version of it and also latest version of tomcat and now my problem is resolved and i am able to create my dynamic web project and thank howlger and nitind for your help

Comment: Just update you eclipse from help-check for updates it works for me